# How to filter out some data from array list to list field in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm trying to filter data in my array list according to my comboBox selected item wise. I still can't solve this problem.

```
public class FoodItem {

    private String name;
    private String type;

    public FoodItem(String n,String t){

        name=n;
        type=t;
    }

    public String getType(){

        return type;
    }

    public String getName(){

        return name;
    }

}

sample.java

<code>
public class A2Demo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtName;
    List listFoodItem = new List();
    JComboBox comboType = new JComboBox();
    FoodItem[] foodItems;
    private final JTextField txtBudget = new JTextField();
    private final JButton btnBudget = new JButton("Search Budget");
    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    A2Demo frame = new A2Demo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public A2Demo() {
        textField.setBounds(93, 247, 134, 28);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        txtBudget.setBounds(183, 11, 86, 20);
        txtBudget.setColumns(10);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 334);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);


        foodItems=new FoodItem[2];
        foodItems[0]=new FoodItem("Chicken Cutlet","Main");
        foodItems[1]=new FoodItem("Chendol","Dessert");
        comboType.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        comboType.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,comboType.getSelectedItem());


            }
        });

        comboType.setBounds(32, 11, 93, 20);
        contentPane.add(comboType);

        for(int i=0; i<foodItems.length; i++)
            comboType.addItem(foodItems[i].getType());


        listFoodItem.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                txtName.setText(listFoodItem.getSelectedItem());


            }
        });

        listFoodItem.setBounds(37, 63, 330, 125);
        contentPane.add(listFoodItem);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        lblName.setBounds(37, 217, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblName);

        txtName = new JTextField();
        txtName.setBounds(93, 214, 134, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtName);
        txtName.setColumns(10);

        contentPane.add(txtBudget);
        btnBudget.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, comboType.getSelectedItem()+ " "+txtBudget.getText());
            }
        });
        btnBudget.setBounds(280, 10, 127, 23);

        contentPane.add(btnBudget);

        contentPane.add(textField);



    }


}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i want to display food name in the list. but combobox changeing to different type my list need to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i want to display food name in the list. but combobox changeing to different type my list need to change according l